# Making sinusoids from a wave file rectangular

Tags: python, signals, signal-processing

I have an on/off keying wav file that I want to process.  To do this, I've read the wav file into an array.  The maximum values are 1, the minimum 0.  I want to transform this array into a representation of whether or not the system was keyed at the given time in the wav file.  So, where there are sinusoids, I want to create a big rectangle in the new buffer, in the time domain.  How can I do this in Python?

Edit: Maybe I can do this with signal processing and SciPy.  But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure this is what you mean. If you simply want to check which values in a numpy array are zero (or smaller than a given value), you can simply use comparison operators on the array, like so

```
import numpy as np
A = np.sin( np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, np.pi/20) ) # some sine wave
A < 0.1 # or == 0.0, gives an array containing True and False
```

But in your case, you probably want to make only a number of consecutive zeros count, since a sine wave may be zero also while the signal is still on. A simple solution would be to take the average of two neighbors, like so

```
average = (A[:-1] + A[1:]) / 2
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: The problem is, a sinusoid is 0 average over a multiple of the wavelengths.

Comment: @horsehair: Use absolute values. ie: `Abs(SineWave)`

Comment: @Shannon - Ah, true.  What about in the presence of low level noise?  I'm only interested in the keying frequency.

Comment: @horsehair I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve. There would be a few ways to filter out low level noise but what's appropriate would depend on your sine wave detection method.